# How to get hidden field array value using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a hidden field in my table.I need to access all array value into controller's action method in rails.Check my below table.

> paymentresult.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :add_payment,:url => {:action => 'add_payment' },remote: true do |f| %>
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
                <th class="text-center">Date</th>
                <th class="text-center">Receipt No.</th>
                <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @result.each do |r| %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag 'infos[]', r %>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><%= check_box_tag :check_value, 1, :id => "checkbox1-1"  %></th>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.id %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.c_date %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.Receipt_No %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i><%= r.v_amount %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
     </tbody>
</table>
 <%= f.submit "Add to payment",:class => "btn btn-success",:id => "switch_car11" %>
<% end %>
```

> payment_controller.rb

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def add_payment
    if params[:commit]
        params[:check_value] == '1' ? remember : forget

    else
        if params[:add_payment][:p_catagory]=="Cheque"
            @chk=true
        end
    end
  end
  private
  def remember
    @reslt=params[:infos]
    @add_payment=AddPayment.create(:p_catagory => params[:add_payment][:p_catagory],:paid_amount => "here i want to add the table's v_amount value",:total_claim => 1 )
  end

end
```

> add_payment.rb:

```
class AddPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :chk_details, :chk_no, :p_catagory, :paid_amount, :total_claim
end
```

I need when user will click on submit button then all array value(i.e-@result) should fetch to add_payment method.I tried by using hidden field but failed to fetch all data.Here my requirement is after submitting the form all value of `@result`should fetch into controller method so that i can save some value from this in DB.

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow. Can you please edit your question and add in all the relevant code (eg the models for a payment result and whatever the "infos" is). Don't put this in the comments. Please edit your question and put the code there.

Comment: @ Taryn :Please check again.

Comment: Hi - looks like you've added controller code - which is good, but I really do need the model code. Mainly I don't know what a payment is and how it related to "infos" - until you show me that in the code... I can't help.

Comment: @ Taryn : forget about infos .I am removing this.Just think i have one model "AddPayment" and i will store some table value in this db table.As per your instruction i am adding model code.

Comment: I put there hidden field for accessing all table values and later failed to do it.I need only one of table value i need which will save into DB.You also can use your own way.

Comment: it's *really super hard* to figure out what you mean when you describe in words what the code should be doing... can you instead show us the code you tried? or even just pseudo-code? I still have no idea what this is supposed to do: `hidden_field_tag 'infos[]', r ` can you tell me: 1) what behaviour you expect given what data? (give sample data and expected output) b) what you observe instead ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76605/discussion-between-rajat-474-and-taryn-east).

Comment: No. I don't have time for that. Just please include all the relevant code in your original question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask